# Run Visual Studio as a domain user and administrator under Windows 8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8, account, administrator

I've just upgraded to Windows 8.1. I have a home machine I use for work, I typically run Visual Studio 2012 as my domain user for work (shift + right click -> run as different user) but use a local account so I don't need to be on the domain.

Having upgraded to Windows 8.1 I'm having two issues:

1. If I'm not on the domain and run VS2012 as my domain user account it tells me my password is incorrect. Adding my computer to the domain remedies this problem.
2. This is the main roadblock: I can't run VS2012 on my domain account in administrator mode. I've added my domain account to Administrators and even logged into the computer with my domain account. If I login with my domain account I can click on VS2012 and I get the UAC popup, so that works. Flipping back to my personal account I can't get it to run as administrator.

I've also right clicked the icon and gone to properties -> shortcut -> advanced and set it to run as administrator there. That checkbox doesn't seem to apply itself when I run as my domain account though. Like I said I've added my domain account to the Administrators group and when I login with my domain account it runs as administrator automatically.

Is there something else I can try?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try running Command Prompt as a local admin and than use command:

```
runas /netonly /user:DOMAIN\username "path to the application.exe"
```